Liquid crystal optical analog to a transistor
I'm new in electrical engineering, and I want to build a simple, clumsy optical transistor. My general idea is that we have light beam (source > drain), which goes through a liquid crystal element (like LCD pixel), which can be light-proof if powered. The LC element is connected to a tiny PV (solar cell) element, which is targeted by a controlling light beam (gate).
UPD: What I want is an optical analog to a transistor - a component that switches an optical signal based on another optical signal. Thanks to commentators below!
Schematic diagram (LCE - liquid crystal element):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So, my questions are:

Are there any ready-made solutions?
If no, which elements should be used for this optical transistor, and how to calculate best parameters for them?

Thank you!

@Transistor thank you! I edited the post, if there are other suggestions, feel free to contact me.

This sounds like a somwhat complicated photo transistor. What's the purpose of the iquid crystal "shutter" in this setup?

@kruemi I could be mistaken, but photo transistor is still an electronic circuit element. What I need is a transistor for optical circuit, i.e. it should operate with light beams (or optical fiber signals).

What do you mean by "electronic circuit element"? It's a transistor that is light sensitive. It conducts when light falls on it and doesn't conduct when there is no light.

Is what you want, an optical analog to a transistor - a component that switches an optical signal based on another optical signal?

To start with, liquid crystals are driven by AC, not DC -- any DC bias causes them to break down quickly.

@MrGerber exactly, yes. Thank you for formulating this correctly!

@DaveTweed thank you! Don't you know by chance, may liquid crystals "blink" with AC? If yes, I guess my idea is totally a garbage :(

It is certainly possible to build a device that exhibits the behaviour that you describe.  It would have to contain a battery and a small active circuit (perhaps a microcontroller to drive the LCD and a photodiode to detect the 'base' light signal).  It could be made quite small I'm sure, perhaps less than 1 cubic inch.  I suspect that trickiest part would be sourcing a suitable LCD element (presumably a small square with sufficient opacity to block a visible-light laser beam).

You could even merge the "base" light beam with the emitter light beam using a suitable prism (and an attenuator to simulate the "photon drop" :)).

See also this excellent EEVBlog video about how to drive an LCD using simple IO... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZP0KxZl5N2o

@anon33 Do you think that PV is insufficient and it has to be a battery in the device? I'd like to avoid that and keep things as simple as it possible :(

@anon33 yes, LCD is a problem. I thought I can find something 1x1 pixel, but apparently this is not a trivial quest

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What you are asking for is just another name of Photo interrupter, photogate, photodiode, phototransistor and so on..
And yes they are commercially available here ,here and so many other websites selling electronic components.

Are you an AI bot? Your various answers seem to miss the point of the question, including this time. Please reply so we know you are human.
